# Normalizing with two neural networks - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two keras models. I concatenate the output layer into a single output. I then use this output in the second model. However, I am unclear about how to normalize my data.

At what point should normalization occur? I normalize before the first model. I also tried normalizing through `tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=0)` and `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=0)`. But when should these be added?

Any guidance or resources are much appreciated.

```
def phi(lat_dim, feature_normaliser, activation):
    model1 = keras.Sequential()
    model1.add(feature_normaliser)
    model1.add(layers.Dense(100,activation= activation))
    model1.add(layers.Dense(lat_dim))
    return model1


def rho(model1, learning_rate, activation):
    model2 = keras.Sequential()
    model2.add(model1)
    model2.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=0,keepdims=True)))
    #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=0)
    model2.add(layers.Dense(100,activation= activation))
    model2.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model2.add(BatchNormalization())
    model2.compile(
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate),
    loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model2
```

Calling the model, results in `nan`:

```
feature_normaliser = layers.Normalization(input_shape=[10], axis=1,name='normaliser')
feature_normaliser.adapt(X_train)
    
phi_output = phi(5, feature_normaliser, 'relu')    
    
rho_output = rho(phi_output, 0.0001, 'relu')
    
history_rho, rho_trained = Model_fit(rho_output,X_train,Y_train,X_val,Y_val, 128, 10)
print(history_rho.history['loss'][-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalize anywhere.

But there are two important normalizations:

- The input "data" should be normalized (usually outside the model)
- The output "data" should be normalized (usually outside the model) and your final activation must be compatible with this normalization

`BatchNormalization` can be used almost anywhere, there is no correct answer. Just like building any model, using `BatchNormalization` is sorf of an art. You test, see if the results are good, change places, etc.

You can, for instance, not normalize the input data and put a `BatchNormalization` right after the input layer. It's a possibility. You can use the `BatchNormalization` before some activations to avoid vanishing gradients and relu locking.

A few `BatchNormalziation` layers in a model can make training a lot faster, but it's not "necessary".

A warining: if  you use `Dropout`, don't use `BatchNormalization` right after. They're not compatible because dropout changes the data distribution (keeps mean, but changes deviation) and this change will make a difference between training and validation that will make the normalization work differently.

Comment: Would it make sense to normalize the output data of the first network before feeding it into the second network?

Comment: To clarify, what does the second bullet point entail, codewise?

Comment: @lisat46788, it might make sense to normalize between the two networks, but it may not be necessary. Some things you just test to see if there is an improvement, and I think this is one of them.

Comment: The second bullet means: `y_train = DoSomeNormalization(original_y_train)`. (The same with `y_test` of course, using the parameters you used for the training data)  - This might be necessary if your data is too big (to avoid needing the network to grow its weights too much), if your data is not in the range provided by the last activation function, etc.